# Tab Bar shows in simulator but not in Interface Builder

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode, interface-builder

On my desktop when I create a Tab Bar application Interface Builder is not displaying it. On my laptop this is not the case.

The problem is kind of hard to explain so I made a video and posted it here.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JO60BcPgWqk

Does anyone know if this behavior is normal?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to add your button to your window directly.  You get the hierarchy wrong here.

You should add your button to the view of the UIViewController of one of your tabs.

Comment: If I open up FirstViewController.xib and add something, next time I try to open it it doesn't show up. Also, the tab bar isn't showing in any of the .xib files.

Comment: There's the tabbar controller inside your xib, which loads the viewcontrollers from other xibs or programmatically.

Comment: How do I add buttons to the tab bar? On my laptop I can just drag and drop tab bar buttons into it, but on my desktoip the tab bar doesn't show in IB.